# Converting EPS(EPT) to PNG/GIF with imagemagick creates extra frame

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert, eps, image-conversion

Using Ghostscript 9.53 on Mac with Imagemagick 7.0.10-59.

The EPS has a Tiff Preview on it, which gets added as a frame in gif or as an extra image for PNG. It started happening after updating imagemagick and ghostscript.

Ghostscript 9.51 and imagemagick 7.0.10-0 without ghostscript delegate did not have this issue.

Command: `magick convert -verbose -density 200 -channel RGBA -colorspace RGB -alpha On my.eps my.gif`

the new output is as follows:

```
/var/folders/zb/ygl385yn3_ggw_bqpdp4940r0000gn/T/magick-3MLz7XbvUU4OJOQBAqLqB-7bteT5s-061 PNG 890x505 890x505+0+0 8-bit sRGB 23054B 0.020u 0:00.014
EPS:/var/folders/zb/ygl385yn3_ggw_bqpdp4940r0000gn/T/magick-tWS3M8-k1os9hbHqWGRzlibuupNgItzv=>/var/folders/zb/ygl385yn3_ggw_bqpdp4940r0000gn/T/magick-tWS3M8-k1os9hbHqWGRzlibuupNgItzv EPS 890x505 890x505+0+0 16-bit sRGB 23054B 0.000u 0:00.000
TIFF:~/Downloads/my.eps=>~/Downloads/my.eps TIFF 321x182 321x182+0+0 8-bit Palette sRGB 256c 148108B 0.000u 0:00.004
~/Downloads/my.eps[0] EPT 890x505 890x505+0+0 16-bit sRGB 23054B 0.010u 0:00.008
~/Downloads/my.eps[0] TIFF 321x182 321x182+0+0 8-bit Palette sRGB 256c 148108B 0.010u 0:00.000
[ghostscript library 9.52] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r200x200' -g890x505 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dEPSCrop  '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/zb/ygl385yn3_ggw_bqpdp4940r0000gn/T/magick-3MLz7XbvUU4OJOQBAqLqB-7bteT5s-06%d' '-f/var/folders/zb/ygl385yn3_ggw_bqpdp4940r0000gn/T/magick-vyRuqlNsQcaG9cv4dJXLql9ChPsp95-g' '-f/var/folders/zb/ygl385yn3_ggw_bqpdp4940r0000gn/T/magick-nK22ULA5kPuCN9Yq8dKM7E8NTQxI82vH'~/Downloads/my.eps=>~/Downloads/my.gif EPT 890x505 890x505+0+0 16-bit Palette sRGB 35c 18001B 0.960u 0:00.139
convert: Invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectoryCheckOrder' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1044.
```

Older version ouput was as follows:

```
'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r200x200' -g890x505 -dEPSCrop  '-sOutputFile=/var/folders/6d/tw_d66k92ld2dc5wvtzxr4y00000gn/T/magick-40084UYHZpdfAwolz%d' '-f/var/folders/6d/tw_d66k92ld2dc5wvtzxr4y00000gn/T/magick-40084Zug0r87QHWuH' '-f/var/folders/6d/tw_d66k92ld2dc5wvtzxr4y00000gn/T/magick-40084JWA1MKLfJ5i7'
/var/folders/6d/tw_d66k92ld2dc5wvtzxr4y00000gn/T/magick-40084UYHZpdfAwolz1 PNG 890x505 890x505+0+0 8-bit sRGB 23054B 0.020u 0:00.013
EPS:/var/folders/6d/tw_d66k92ld2dc5wvtzxr4y00000gn/T/magick-40084Rxd2cgpYXsmR=>/var/folders/6d/tw_d66k92ld2dc5wvtzxr4y00000gn/T/magick-40084Rxd2cgpYXsmR EPS 890x505 890x505+0+0 16-bit sRGB 23054B 0.010u 0:00.000
~/Desktop/my.eps EPT 890x505 890x505+0+0 16-bit sRGB 23054B 0.000u 0:00.000
~/Desktop/my.eps=>~/Desktop/my.gif EPT 890x505 890x505+0+0 16-bit PaletteBilevelAlpha sRGB 3c 9061B 0.830u 0:00.121
```

Is there a way for me to tell imagemagick to ignore tiff preview?

[EPS File here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uDqIwbibV8Aebk_gdZo3MuvHZW5s9-uS/view?usp=sharing)

[Bad Gif here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1diFPMpLVPlDxz7LxGtso9V04AZYnvxiD/view?usp=sharing)

** Updated file links

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick 7, use magick not magick convert and not convert. Also if you have only one frame/page and want to keep on that, then add [0] to your input image. So try

`magick -verbose -density 200 -channel RGBA -colorspace RGB -alpha On my.eps[0] my.gif`

Comment: my.eps[0]  does work but I am more confused as to why I don't have to do this with older version, it just ignores the TIFF Preview. Also technically I don't have multiple pages/frames only a tiff preview in the EPS

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the reason. Please post a bug report on the ImageMagick GitHub page at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick